# Bulk and dynamic viscosity in the atmosphere

Tags: fluid-dynamics, atmospheric-science, viscosity, navier-stokes

I'm studying the physics of the atmosphere but I'm struggling with the matter of viscosity (Navier-Stokes equation) for gravito-acoustic waves. From Landau-Lifschitz :

$$
(T)_{ij} = -p\delta_{ij} + \eta(\partial_j\mathbf{v}_i + \partial_i\mathbf{v}_{j} - \frac{2}{3}\delta_{ij}\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}) +  + \zeta\delta_{ij}\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}
$$

where $\eta$ is the dynamic viscosity, $\zeta$ is the second viscosity, $\mathbf{v}$ is the velocity, $p$ is the pressure, and $\delta$ the Kronecker delta.

My question is, in a windy viscous stratified atmosphere (up to 500km) how should I treat the viscous stress tensor $T$?

Should I take into account both the dynamic viscosity (normal viscosity) and the second viscosity?

Can I consider the viscosity coefficients $\eta, \zeta$ to be constant?

What about the Stokes assumption $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{v} = 0$?

Considering viscosity can I still use the adiabatic assumption to settle the Navier-Stokes equation?

(More specifically) For gravito-acoustic propagation should I consider shear effects as well ?

Comment: See also [EarthScience.SE] Stack Exchange.